# MySQL Workbench EER Diagram - hide columns

Tags: mysql-workbench

In older versions of MySQL Workbench there was an "Object Notation menu" option `Workbench (PKs and FKs only)`, which would show only columns that are primary and foreign keys.

This is removed from [Workbench 6.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-data-modeling-menus.html#wb-object-notation-menu).

For large tables it was useful to only show primary and foreign keys. Is there a way to do this in current MySQL Workbench versions?

Comment: That doesn't exist in 6.2.x either (tested 6.2.5 here).